# Implementing Future in CLDC 1.1

Tags: blackberry, mobile, java-me, concurrency

I really like the concept of FutureValues. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FutureValue

And although I'm working in a CLDC 1.1 environment (Blackberry), I'm wondering if it is
possible to implement it with the available wait-notify / Threading support in Java 1.3.
Basically I want to create:

1. ExecutorService - to start threads
2. Each thread then communicates with its Future on completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *might* look [here](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/intro.html), which formed the basis for the java.util.concurrent stuff... I don't know if you can get it to work on CLDC 1.1... but worth a look.